# can pydantic validate fields on update while still using optional fields that are not provided to the constructor

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, validation, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I have a simple pydantic class with 1 optional field and one required field with a constraint. I'd like to ensure the constraint item is validated on both create and update while keeping the Optional field optional.

If I don't use the MyConfig dataclass attribute with a validate_assignment attribute true, I can create the item with no table_key attribute but the s3_target.target = 'BadPath' line of code is allowed. If I don't include the dataclass attribute then I don't have to provide a table_key upon creation but the s3_target update line is allowed to run.

Is there any way to easily make pydantic support both scenarios?

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

from pydantic.class_validators import Optional

class MyConfig:
    validate_assignment = True


@dataclass(config=MyConfig)
class S3Target(BaseModel):
    table_key: Optional[str] = None
    # target: str = Field(regex=r'^s3://([^/]+)/(.*?([^/]+))/$', description="must be a valid s3 path", )
    target: constr(regex=r'^s3://([^/]+)/(.*?([^/]+))/$')


s3_target = S3Target(target='s3://bucket/location/')
s3_target.target = 'BadPath'
```

I tried adding the dataclass with validate_assignment=true and expected the Optional Field to stay optional and not have to pass this into the S3Target constructor. I tried to set validate_assignment to False and it also did not allow the item to be created without a table_key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pydantic supports validating on assignment through the `validate_assignment` option on its [ModelConfig](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/model_config/) class. Set it to `True` for the desired behavior.

```py
class S3Target(BaseModel):
    table_key: Optional[str] = None
    # target: str = Field(regex=r'^s3://([^/]+)/(.*?([^/]+))/$', description="must be a valid s3 path", )
    target: constr(regex=r'^s3://([^/]+)/(.*?([^/]+))/$')

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
```

There's no need to use a `dataclass` decorator to achieve this behavior. (And I don't know how to get this behavior while using the dataclass decorator)

Comment: This only works, if `S3Target` is _not_ a data class, but a regular model. OP specified it with the `dataclass` decorator.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Correct that this only works without the data class decorator. The OP described trying to achieve this behavior both with and without the `dataclass` decorator, and asked how to "make pydantic to support both scenarios". I understood this to mean that using dataclasses was not a requirement.

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify that `dataclass` is not used in this solution

Comment: Thanks, I thought the dataclass was a shorter way to add write_assignment to multiple dataclasses but I guess it doesn't work the way I expected.